# Unable to run a subprocess in PyCharm to run a js script using node

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess

I'm trying to run a .js script in PyCharm (Python 3.10) using the subprocess.run() function. But I keep getting a WinError2. It runs fine when I run it using command prompt, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in PyCharm.

```
runnable_file_loc = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
    __file__), RUNNABLE_FILENAME)

res = subprocess.run(
    ["node", runnable_file_loc], capture_output=True)
token_str = res.stdout
token = json.loads(token_str)
```

This is the error I'm getting. I'm not sure if it's a PATH issue or not. I've looked into up, but I've hit a wall.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    doThing()
  File "C:\\main.py", line 48, in doThing
    res = subprocess.run(
  File "C:\\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: it cannot find `node` either provide the full path to node or add `shell=True` ... its not  a problem with your path to your js file

Comment: I've added node to both my computer's PATH and my PyCharm's path but I still get the same error. When I do 'shell=TRUE' the code "runs" but it's only outputting an empty byte for the stdout. @JoranBeasley

Comment: `shell=True` will use your path ... without it ... it wont and you must provide the full path...